# Would it be possible... to install wine in "bash on ubuntu on windows"

Tags: wine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After getting the new ubuntu on windows from microsoft, my head is about to explode. So far, most of the things that I've tried to do haven't worked. Like open nautilus, but I already knew that wasn't going to work. What seems to me to be an interesting and possibly extremely useful idea, it to install wine on "bash on ubuntu on windows" (phew, that's a lot to say). Does anybody here think it will be possible? Any problems that might get in the way?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: good question, not sure that I can answer it. perhaps, debugging windows applications?

Comment: Well it's only Bash and not a VM, so no, probably not. But the real question is, why do you want to run Wine? You have Windows. You want to run Windows programs in Windows by running them under Wine under Bash?

Comment: That way, one could install cmd on wine, and then run ubuntu from cmd! Excuse my stupidity >_<

Comment: @MortyV I fail to see any practical applications of what you are trying to do.

Comment: yeah, I sort of thought I had something for a moment, but I don't think I do

Comment: oooh. recursive.

Comment: I can see at least one benefit - some legacy Windows applications don't run at all under current versions. This might be a way to get them running.

Comment: @NathanOsman That's a good idea! Thus far, there is no port or replacement for the x window system though. I don't know if it's possible, so much is still being developed.

Comment: @MortyV sure there is: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/

Comment: @NathanOsman the link is broken. But it seems like it exists. Holy moly, BoUoW is like a course on operating systems.

Comment: @MortyV looks like the entire SourceForge network is down. In the meantime, here's some more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xming

Comment: yup, that's what it was. I'm checking it out now

Comment: @NathanOsman Can't you use compatibility mode to run legacy programs?

Comment: @wjandrea in theory, yes. In practice, no. Some apps simply refuse to run.

Comment: Yes, but you have to be on the insider builds, see [Wine on WSL](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=Wine%20on%20WSL&d=4774656682760155&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=ObdQgTU0pm97Q0Z4Siwauj50R9JnllAy)

Comment: I don't have a solid answer, but the utility of using Wine in WSL will probably mostly depend on how much Wine's 16-bit [thunking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunking#Interoperability) depends on aspects of the Linux kernel that Microsoft hasn't cloned. (Generally, old Windows apps don't run on modern Windows because Microsoft didn't bother to port the 32-to-16-bit thunking to 64-bit versions of Windows.)

Comment: Wine allows Linux users limited ability to run Windows applications. Why on earth would you want it to run on WSL which gives Linux Universe  limited ability on Windows?

Comment: The reason I want this is because my build machine is cross compiling to windows and I want to use wine to run the test suite. However, I always try and replicate my build machines on my dev machine and my dev machine is windows; therefore I use Bash on Windows for the Ubuntu environment (to replicate the build machine) and then want to use wine to run the test suite.

Answer (score 6):

@EEDDGG mentioned in comments that it works in insider builds.

Since Creators Update, it also runs on normal builds.

`sudo apt-get install wine` fails by default, because package `wine` also depends on 32bit version of wine and 32bit is not supported on WSL. `wine64` can't be installed alone, because `wine64` strangely also depends on some 32bit packages.

To install:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

This will allow installation of 32bit apps. However WSL can't load 32bit executables, therefore you must call `wine64` and you can only run 64bit applications. Example:

```
wine64 cmd.exe
```

Of course you need an X-server for gui applications (like `wine64 notepad.exe`).

Comment: It launches wine utilities ok but for any  external software it outputs `/usr/bin/wine: 40: exec: /usr/lib/wine/wine: Exec format error`

Comment: are you sure, that you tested with a 64 bit application? `wine64 /mnt/c/Program\ Files/7-Zip/7zFM.exe` works perfectly fine for me. (`wine64` instead of `wine` is not enough, `/mnt/c/Program\ Files/7-Zip/7zFM.exe` has to be 64 bit as well.)

Comment: that is right, it would be nice to extend this answer with 32bit applications support too

Comment: N.B. As of Feb 2020, you may need to specify 'wine-stable'.